# Gzoom subgurim asp.net don´t work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, subgurim-maps

we're using a subgurim gmaps for show to the users maps in a web application in asp.net web forms. Now in the map we're loading a kml and after with information of the database create a polyline that represent a route of a employee.

Using map.GZoom = 15 for example for apply a zoom this don't work, always appear in the same zoom independent of the value. It's strange because when loading the map if you see zooming, but then this is not maintained.

This is the method used in the page load

```
Private Sub cargarMapa()
        Try
            GMapTrampas.GZoom = 10 ' Zoom
            GMapTrampas.Height = 600
            GMapTrampas.enableHookMouseWheelToZoom = True
            'Load the kml save in google sites
            Dim rutaMapa As String = implementacionMapa.listarRutaMapaGeneral()
            GMapTrampas.Add(New GGeoXml(rutaMapa))
            GMapTrampas.DataBind()            
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: have you checked if there are any java script errors?

Comment: also it would help if you could share some of your code

Comment: Yes I checked in the console for javascript errors and I have not found errors

Comment: are you running this function when the page first loads?

Comment: i tend to use the JavaScript to change the zoom, i haven't had much luck with the vb.net code

Comment: in the first load no, after

Comment: that might be your problem, just for testing purposes, try change the zoom on load?

Comment: checking the error with the zoom, the error occur when add a GGeoXml that put in the map a kml save in a url, but this GGeoXml is required